# HTTP/HTTPS Proxy Server

Tags: python, http, networking, https

I am making my own proxy server implementation in python that can serve all http/https requests of browser using socket programming. Here is my code:

```
from socket import error as SocketError
import requests
import urllib3
import os.path
import socket
import random
import errno
import os
import sys
import ssl

def MainServerController():

    Proxy()

def Proxy():
    port_addr = ('localhost', 12345)

    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile='certificate.pem', keyfile='private_key.pem')

    # Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening
    tcpSerSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpSerSock.bind(port_addr)

    
    tcpSerSock.listen(40)

    while True:

        # Start receiving data from the client
        print(f'\nReady to serve at {port_addr}')
        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()

        
        tcpCliSock = context.wrap_socket(tcpCliSock)
        
        print('Received a connection from:', addr)
        message = tcpCliSock.recv(40960).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

        if message == '':
            continue

        print(f'\'{message}\'')

        # Extract the filename from the given message
        if message.split(' ')[1].startswith('http') or message.split(' ')[1].startswith('https'):
            filename = message.split(' ')[1].split('//')[1]
        else:
            filename = message.split(':')[0].split(' ')[1]

        try:
            response = requests.get(f"http://{filename}", verify=False)
        except:
            print(f"Not found {filename}")
            continue

        
        try:
            tcpCliSock.send(response.content + b"\r\n")
        except SocketError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                print(f'Connection Reset By Peer! {filename} ')
            continue
    tcpSerSock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    tcpCliSock.close()
MainServerController()
```

The above code is perfectly running for all requests except for https if I am commenting this line:

```
tcpCliSock = context.wrap_socket(tcpCliSock)
```

And giving not secure connection page on browser for https requests but by using this line neither http nor https request is served and throwing error like :

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\RSA\https.py", line 36, in Proxy
    tcpCliSock = context.wrap_socket(tcpCliSock)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1066, in _create
    self._sslobj = self._context._wrap_socket(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ssl.SSLError: Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:795)
```

The key and certificate is generated by :

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out certificate.pem -keyout private_key.pem
```

Can somebody help me in this?